# how to Remove the last two columns from the second DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

here in line 9 is is not working. If the assertion fails, print the error and show the data from both DataFrames. what is read_parquet ?

```
import pandas as pd
import pytest

def read_and_compare_parquet_files(file1_path, file2_path):
    try:
        # Read the Parquet files
        df1 = pd.read_parquet(file1_path)  # Replace with the actual path of file 1
        df2 = pd.read_parquet(file2_path)  # Replace with the actual path of file 2

        # Remove the last two columns from the second DataFrame
        df2_modified = df2.iloc[:, :-2]

        # Use pytest's assert statement to check if the data frames are identical
        assert df1.equals(df2_modified), "DataFrames are not identical"

        return "DataFrames are identical"

    except AssertionError as e:
        # If the assertion fails, print the error and show the data from both DataFrames
        print(e)
        print("\nDataFrame from File 1:")
        print(df1)
        print("\nModified DataFrame from File 2:")
        print(df2_modified)
        return "Assertion failed. DataFrames are displayed above."

# Example usage
file1_path = '/path/to/file1.parquet'  # Replace with the actual path of file 1
file2_path = '/path/to/file2.parquet'  # Replace with the actual path of file 2

result = read_and_compare_parquet_files(file1_path, file2_path)
print(result)
```

Comment: Im not so sure the problem is line 9 -- if df1 is a data frame and df2 is df1 with two extra columns, then this should work fine. That makes me question if df1 and df2 look how you think they look. Have you tried examining those objects after using `pd.read_parquet` (but before taking any columns off)?

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? Is the data in your two files the same? Did you change the location of `file1_path` and `file2_path` to point to actual parquet files? Is it throwing an error? No error? Are you asking us what the function [`read_parquet` does](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_parquet.html)?

Comment: Do you mean what is ```pd.read_parquet```, or something else?.  If you are talking about ```pd.read_parquet```, have you read the pandas docs?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The short answer is: There is no problem with this code and it works exactly as it ought to. Change `file1_path` and `file2_path` to point to two different parquet files and run.

Comment: Welcome. Please use `print(df.head())`, as a start, to post a bit of data. Then have a look at [ask] and [mre] for guidance on asking questions more likely to receive answers.